# Delphi Table sorting

Tags: delphi, sorting

I have a simple problem which gave em a headache

I need to sort integers in a Database table TDBGrid ( its ABS database from component ace ) with the following order

- 0
- 1
- 11
- 111
- 121
- 2
- 21
- 211
- 22
- 221

and so on

which means every number starting with 1 should be under 1

- 1
- 11
- 111
- 5
- 55

can anyone help me?

thanks

Comment: If they are integers how to make a difference from 01 and 1? May be you meant strings? And if they are strings, the normal sorting should work.

Comment: Use strings instead of integers!

Comment: the normal sorting doesnt work for simple reason 22 is smaller than 0111

Comment: I would like to use string but i have some condition set that can be only applied on integer

Comment: 22 is smaller then 0111 but "22" is greater then "0111"

Comment: thanks for the answer but is there a way i can do it with integer?

Comment: I don't quite understand how you make a difference between 0111 and 111 if they are integers?

Comment: Let's say that they don't have 0 before number and you don't want to convert them to strings, then only way I could see is to compare the same number of digits. For example for comparing 1033 and 12 you multiply 12 by 10^2 and comparing 1033 and 1200

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to provide a little more information, such as what you mean by "table" (is it a database table, and if so what database, what is the column definition, etc.). If you want people to help you, you need to remember that we have no information about your problem except what you tell us in your question - we can't see your code or read your mind from here. You need to provide enough specifics so we have the info to help you. :)

Comment: I have edited my question thank you
I apologize if i wasnt clear enough please read again

Comment: > *"even without the 0 111 will be after 22"* - What difference does it make? You can't store 0111 to an integer variable, it will hold 111. You, simply, can't have integers. Work with strings and where you have a condition that can only be applied to an integer, convert them to integers.

Comment: read the question again please
i tried with string and its same, it sort them ascending and descending order, not the way i need, i gave a sample of how i want it to look in the question

Comment: write in a question your code of your sorting with strings

Comment: @user - Add a 'ListBox' to a form, set its `Sorted` property to true. Add a 'Button' to the form, double click it. In the click handler put `ListBox1.Items.Add('1');` and all of the others. Run your project and click the button. Then tell me what you see..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to get stuff in the right order:

1. Convert the original number to a string;
2. Right-pad with zeroes until you have a string of 3 characters wide;
3. (optional) Convert back to integer.

Then sorting should always work the way you want. Probably it's best to let the database do that for you. In MySQL you'd do something like this:

```
select RPAD(orderid,3,'0') as TheOrder 
from MyTable 
order by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran this in SQL Server Management Studio - note I mixed up the rows in the input so they were not in sorted order:

```
create table #temp( ID Char(3));
insert into #temp (ID) 
      select '111' union
      select '221';
      select '0' union 
      select '21' union
      select '1' union 
      select '11' union
      select '211' union
      select '121' union
      select '2' union
      select '22' union
select * from #temp order by ID;
```

I got the following output:

```
ID
----
0  
1  
11 
111
121
2  
21 
211
22 
221

(10 row(s) affected)
```

If you're getting different results, you're doing something wrong. However, it's hard to say what because you didn't post anything about how you're retrieving the data from the database.

Edit: Some clarification by the poster indicates that the display is in a `TDBGrid` attached to a table using `Component Ace ABS Database`. If that indeed is the case, then the answer is to create an index on the indicated column, and then set the table's `IndexName` property to use that index.

Comment: its a component, it sorts them by default, TDBGrid and as i said the database is ABS from component ace, its a file driven database.

Comment: `TDBGrid` does NOT sort anything by default. You have to do that either by putting an index on the table and then using that index order, or by adding an `ORDER BY` in your SQL.

Comment: there is an index so how do i do achieve the sorting i need

Comment: Set the table's IndexName property to the name of the index on the column.

Comment: @user - If your component is performing a different sort, then you should include that information in the first version of the question. And you should tag your question so, so that it becomes a database related question, not general sorting.

Comment: @Sertac, the poster is using a `TDBGrid` attached to a table from `Component Ace ABS`. I feel like we're trying to pull teeth here trying to get information from the poster - 15 comments to the original question, and it wasn't until I posted an answer that we found out it was a `TDBGrid`, and now there are 5 comments to my answer (six with this one).

Comment: it doesnt work with index too,
same thing it sort them ascending and descending

Comment: No, it doesn't. If it does, you need to contact `Component Ace` and tell them they have a serious bug in their components. I'd be willing to bet that's not the problem, though.

Comment: I am very sorry this is my first post, i apologize for that.
i hope someone can help me now that u know more information and if there is something else u need to know i will inform.

Comment: @user - What's the data type of the field?

Comment: first wast integer then i changed it to string as some sugested

Comment: @user - My suggestion would be to start a new project with few lines of code and a table from scratch that would duplicate the problem and contact ace support. As you have found out from this answer and the comments to the question, string sorting should give the result that you want.

Answer (score 0):

`select cast(INT_FIELD as varchar(9)) as I
from TABxxx
order by 1`